# Build standalone nextjs project but get Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 when running server.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, build, config, server-side-rendering

When i build standalone nextjs project I get file server.js and I try to running my server.js file and get this error

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting node_modules, .cache folder and package-lock.json and run npm install again.

Answer (score 1):

consider that the file in your folder **should** be page.js or page.jsx. and of course yk that the url should be just the file name.